# How to build smart-contract in network etherium on solidity via python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a smart contract written in solidity, I want to generate this smart contract directly from Python and place it on the etherium network programmatically, automatically, is it possible ? If so, how? Any examples? An example of a smart contract I have: [Safe Remote Purchase](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase)

Comment: why do I get negative votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a python script and use web3.py to deploy your contract or call its functions, if that is what you mean.

Check [web3.py documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Also, the answer provided to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/77142/call-smart-contract-function-in-python-script)
 question may be useful to you.